# Sharing Session across multiple WCF service Hosted on Same machine

Tags: silverlight, wcf, session

I have Silverlight application having multiple WCF services as Business Layer. We are storing 
some values like timeZoneID in session which can be used across all wcf service.
We are able save values in session and also session can be shared across multiple wcf services , But we are getting issue of session overriding when multiple users access application simultaneously.
It means Session is shared across multiple service as well as multiple users also. which is wrong.
Can you please provide a solution for this issue to avoid session sharing across multiple users.

Thanks,

Comment: can you show some code on how you are using the Session?

Answer (score 2):

Store your session information outside of the WCF session mechanism.
Stored them in the database and use an identifier to store/retrieve the session information on each service. If the client passes the same ID to the services he/she will retrieve his/her settings on each service.

Comment: +1 exactly - persistent session info belongs in a persistent store, i.e. a database - that's the only real solution that'll work in a production environment...

Comment: As an added benefit, you also have support for load balancing for free.